# intentando generar una sucesion fibonacci 0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34 con bucle for y sin la coma final

Tags: java, bucle-for, fibonacci

Este es mi código,si no le pongo condiciones me sale todo pero me añade una coma final y al intentar filtrar la ultima posición de i con un if() me omite los dos ultimos numeros.

```
public class EjercicioFibonacci {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a=0,b=1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (i==0) {
                System.out.print(a+","+b+",");
            }else if(i==3) {
                a=a+b;
                b=a+b;
                System.out.print(a+","+b);
            }else {
                a=a+b;
                b=a+b;
                System.out.print(a+","+b+",");
            }



        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Añade la coma siempre y después de salir del `for` usa substring para quedarte con todos los caracteres menos el último.

Comment: Pero aquí el problema de que no le salgan los 2 últimos números es problema del recorrido de la i.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De la manera que estás haciendo el recorrido, deberías establecer las condicionales de esta manera.. **con dos if consecutivos**, para que en la **primera vuelta del bucle for**, te lea el primer **if** se cumpla la condición, y continúe y también entre en el **else**, valiendo `i=0`. Así no te faltará una vuelta más en el for, como te estaba faltando. No sé si me expliqué bien.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (i==0) {
                System.out.print(a+","+b+",");
            }
            if(i==3) {
                a=a+b;
                b=a+b;
                System.out.print(a+","+b);
            }else {
                a=a+b;
                b=a+b;
                System.out.print(a+","+b+",");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

Puedes hacerlo fácilmente de la siguiente manera sin necesidad de `if-else` y solucionando el problema de la última coma:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n1 = 0, n2 = 1, n3, cantidad = 10;

        // Imprimir 0 y 1
        System.out.print(n1 + ", " + n2);

        // Comienza desde 2 porque 0 y 1 ya fueron imprimidos anteriormente
        for (int i = 2; i < cantidad; ++i) {
            n3 = n1 + n2;
            System.out.print(", " + n3);
            n1 = n2;
            n2 = n3;
        }
    }
```

**Resultado:**
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34